# Merge two SELECT in one only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to merge this two query in one only with this 4 columns.

Query 1:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN
         (
( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] < 30 ) 
            OR 
            (
               [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] < 30
            )
         )
      THEN
         'PC_Less_30dB' 
   END
   AS PC_Less_30dB, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         (
( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] > 30 ) 
            OR 
            (
               [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] > 30
            )
         )
      THEN
         'PC_More_30dB' 
   END
   AS PC_More_30dB 
FROM
   RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson 
WHERE
   (
      [MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL
   )
   AND MKP_Number = 5830656 
   SELECT
      CASE
         WHEN
            (
               Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago < 1278 
            )
         THEN
            'CL_Less_3_5_Years' 
      END
      AS CL_Less_3_5_Years, 
      CASE
         WHEN
            (
               Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago > 1277 
            )
         THEN
            'CL_More_3_5_Years' 
      END
      AS CL_More_3_5_Years 
   FROM
      RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson 
   WHERE
      (
         [MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL
      )
      AND MKP_Number = 2098914
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to format a bit better, so the query can be read without sideways scrolling.

Comment: What is the key field to join these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `MKP_Number` different in two queries? Is it right?

As variant you can try to use `FULL JOIN`

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(q1.MKP_Number,q2.MKP_Number) MKP_Number,
    q1.PC_Less_30dB,
    q1.PC_More_30dB,
    q2.CL_Less_3_5_Years,
    q2.CL_More_3_5_Years
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MKP_Number,
            CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] < 30 ) OR ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] < 30) )
                THEN 'PC_Less_30dB'
            END AS PC_Less_30dB,
            CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] > 30 ) OR ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] > 30) )
                THEN 'PC_More_30dB'
            END AS PC_More_30dB
        FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
        WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL)
        AND MKP_Number =5830656
    ) q1
FULL JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MKP_Number,
            CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago<1278 )
                THEN 'CL_Less_3_5_Years'
            END AS CL_Less_3_5_Years,
             CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago>1277 )
                THEN 'CL_More_3_5_Years'
            END AS CL_More_3_5_Years
        FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
        WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL)
        AND MKP_Number =2098914
    ) q2
ON q1.MKP_Number=q2.MKP_Number
```

Three subqueries

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(q1.MKP_Number,q2.MKP_Number,q3.MKP_Number) MKP_Number, -- !!!
    q1.PC_Less_30dB,
    q1.PC_More_30dB,
    q2.CL_Less_3_5_Years,
    q2.CL_More_3_5_Years,
    q3.CL_Asl -- !!!
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MKP_Number,
            CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] < 30 ) OR ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] < 30) )
                THEN 'PC_Less_30dB'
            END AS PC_Less_30dB,
            CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] > 30 ) OR ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] > 30) )
                THEN 'PC_More_30dB'
            END AS PC_More_30dB
        FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
        WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL)
        AND MKP_Number =5830656
    ) q1
FULL JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MKP_Number,
            CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago<1278 )
                THEN 'CL_Less_3_5_Years'
            END AS CL_Less_3_5_Years,
             CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago>1277 )
                THEN 'CL_More_3_5_Years'
            END AS CL_More_3_5_Years
        FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
        WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL)
        AND MKP_Number =2098914
    ) q2
ON q1.MKP_Number=q2.MKP_Number
FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MKP_Number,
      CASE WHEN ( Mkp_Lastsalesheacustomercontributionamount != 0 ) AND (Mkp_Lastsalesheainsuranceamount != 0 )
        THEN 'CL_Asl'
      END AS CL_Asl
    FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
    WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL) AND MKP_Number =5338443  
  ) q3
ON q3.MKP_Number=ISNULL(q1.MKP_Number,q2.MKP_Number)
```

I think the following variant will be better

```
SELECT
    MKP_Number,

    CASE WHEN ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL AND MKP_Number =5830656)
        AND ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] < 30  OR [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] < 30) THEN 'PC_Less_30dB'
    END AS PC_Less_30dB,

    CASE WHEN ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL AND MKP_Number =5830656)
        AND ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] > 30  OR [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight]) > 30 THEN 'PC_More_30dB'
    END AS PC_More_30dB,

    CASE WHEN ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL AND MKP_Number =2098914)
        AND (Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago<1278) THEN 'CL_Less_3_5_Years'
    END AS CL_Less_3_5_Years,

    CASE WHEN ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL AND MKP_Number =2098914)
        AND (Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago>1277) THEN 'CL_More_3_5_Years'
    END AS CL_More_3_5_Years,

    CASE WHEN ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL AND MKP_Number =5338443)
      AND (Mkp_Lastsalesheacustomercontributionamount != 0 AND Mkp_Lastsalesheainsuranceamount != 0) THEN 'CL_Asl'
    END AS CL_Asl
FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL AND MKP_Number =5830656)
   OR ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL AND MKP_Number =2098914)
   OR ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL AND MKP_Number =5338443)
```

Comment: how to add a 3rd query? like

SELECT
            MKP_Number,
            CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheacustomercontributionamount != 0 ) AND (Mkp_Lastsalesheainsuranceamount != 0 ) 
                THEN 'CL_Asl'
            END AS CL_Asl
        FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
        WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL)
  AND MKP_Number =5338443

Comment: @Mariano - I edited my answer. But I think better rewrite your query. I'll try to do id.

Comment: @Mariano - I added one more variant for three subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `UNION` to merge the queries results, but the result of each of the queries must contain the same columns.

In the following example, `NULL` values are set for irrelevant columns in each query, and a fake `Result_Type` column is added so that you know from which query each result comes from.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] < 30 ) OR ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] < 30) )
        THEN 'PC_Less_30dB'
        END AS PC_Less_30dB,
    CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] > 30 ) OR ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] > 30) )
        THEN 'PC_More_30dB'
        END AS PC_More_30dB,
    NULL AS CL_Less_3_5_Years,  
    NULL AS CL_More_3_5_Years,
    'PC' AS Result_Type
    FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
    WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL)
    AND MKP_Number =5830656
UNION ALL           
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago<1278 )
        THEN 'CL_Less_3_5_Years'
        END AS CL_Less_3_5_Years,
     CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago>1277 )
        THEN 'CL_More_3_5_Years'
        END AS CL_More_3_5_Years,
    NULL AS PC_Less_30dB,
    NULL AS PC_More_30dB,
    'CL' AS Result_Type
    FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson
    WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL)
    AND MKP_Number =2098914
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
SELECT  
T1.PC_Less_30dB,T1.PC_More_30dB,T2.CL_Less_3_5_Years,T2.CL_More_3_5_Years  
FROM   
(SELECT   
CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] < 30 ) OR        ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] < 30) )  
    THEN 'PC_Less_30dB'  
    END AS PC_Less_30dB,  
CASE WHEN  ( ( [MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexLeft] > 30 ) OR   ([MKP_LastHearTestFletcherIndexRight] > 30) )  
    THEN 'PC_More_30dB'  
    END AS PC_More_30dB  
    FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson  
    WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NULL)  
AND MKP_Number =5830656) as T1,  
(SELECT   
CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago<1278 )  
    THEN 'CL_Less_3_5_Years'  
    END AS CL_Less_3_5_Years,  
CASE WHEN  ( Mkp_Lastsalesheadaysago>1277 )  
    THEN 'CL_More_3_5_Years'  
    END AS CL_More_3_5_Years  
FROM RPT.ANIDIM_MarketingPerson  
WHERE ([MKP_LastSalesHEADate] IS NOT NULL)  
AND MKP_Number =2098914) as T2
```